# NewtonSoft JsonConvert - Deserialize a JSON object that looks like { “@nil”: “true” }

Tags: json, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize the following JSON returned by a rest service:

```
[{
"Vehicle": {
  "Id": "1",
   "RenewalDate": {
    "@nil": "true"
  }     
}}]
```

The service seems to translate XML to JSON and hence the XML nil is included as part of the JSON string.

Please let me know how to handle this in Newtonsoft deserialize method?

The deserialization works fine if Renewal Date is included in the string.

Comment: What does the value of `"RenewalDate"` look like when it is not `nil` in the original XML?  What c# model are you trying to deserialize the JSON as?  If you just do `JToken.Parse(jsonString)` it should work fine so please share your target model for which deserialization fails.

Comment: Any chance of an [mcve] for this?  If you show us what you have done so far and exactly where it fails, we're more likely to be able to give you a solution you can actually use.  See [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.

Answer (score 6):

In the absence of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem, I'm going to assume you are trying to deserialize to a list of classes that look like this:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public DateTime? RenewalDate { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
}
```

And, deserialization is failing for the property `"RenewalDate"` because, rather than a `null` value appearing in the JSON, a object containing a translated [`xsi:nil="true"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute is present.

One way to solve this would be to introduce the following [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm):

```
public class NullableStructConverter<T> : JsonConverter where T : struct
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Nullable<T>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(objectType);
        if (underlyingType == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Type {0} is not nullable", objectType));
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            return null;
        if (token.WasNilXmlElement())
            return null;
        return token.ToObject(underlyingType, serializer);
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    public static bool WasNilXmlElement(this JToken token)
    {
        if (token == null)
            return true;
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Null)
            return true;
        var obj = token as JObject;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            // Check if all properties were translated from XML attributes
            // and one was translated from xsi:nil = true
            // There might be namespaces present as well, e.g.
            // "@xmlns:p3": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            if (obj.Properties().All(p => p.Name.StartsWith("@"))
                && obj.Properties().Any(p => p.Name == "@nil" || p.Name.EndsWith(":nil") && p.Value.ToString() == "true"))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    Converters = { new NullableStructConverter<DateTime>() } 
    // Whatever other settings you require.
};
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject[]>(json, settings);
```

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TJYxii).

Another option would be to load the JSON into a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) hierarchy, replace all JSON objects that were translated from `nil` XML elements with `null` JSON values, then finally deserialize to your model.  First, introduce the following extension method which uses `WasNilXmlElement()` from the first solution:

```
public static partial class JTokenExtensions
{
    public static JToken ReplaceNilXmlElementObjectsWithNull(this JToken root)
    {
        var rootContainer = root as JContainer;
        if (rootContainer == null)
            return root;
        var list = rootContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()
            .OfType<JObject>()
            .Where(o => o.WasNilXmlElement())
            .ToList();
        foreach (var obj in list)
        {
            var replacement = JValue.CreateNull();
            if (obj.Parent != null)
                obj.Replace(replacement);
            if (root == obj)
                root = replacement;
        }
        return root;
    }
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    // Whatever settings you require.
};
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(json, settings)
    .ReplaceNilXmlElementObjectsWithNull()
    .ToObject<RootObject[]>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

This solution avoids the need for a `JsonConverter` for each nullable type.  Working [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hUsIX3).